# É possível utilizar a câmera do celular em um Web App com React?

Tags: aplicação-web, react

Pessoal preciso desenvolver um web app com React, "não é React Native", e vai ser necessário utilizar a câmera do celular só para tirar uma foto, isso é possível com React? existem alguma lib pra isso?

Fiz uma busca no Google encontrei isso: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-camera

Algem já utilizou? funciona como esperado?

Obrigado!

Comment: você se refere a uma aplicação web que utiliza a câmera do celular? geralmente isso é feito através de um input file. Por estar rodando em um celular ele já vai dar como opção de entrada a câmera e você pode deixar essa entrada como padrão. Adicione o seu código à pergunta.

Comment: Isso, mais eu testei este input ai, não funcionou como esperado em alguns dos aparelhos que testei.

Comment: inclua o seu código a pergunta

Comment: aqui vc encontra exatamente o que quer!
https://react-image-upload.surge.sh/

Answer (score 1):

A sua dúvida na verdade deveria ser,

#### *é possível usar a câmera do celular em uma aplicação Web*?

A resposta é sim **mas** apenas em alguns poucos navegadores. Ainda assim com certas limitações.

Lembre-se que o React é apenas uma lib para vc criar interfaces reativas, Se o sistema que você está usando, não fornece acesso a tal recurso, não vai ser o React que irá fornecer ok?

Fonte: [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=camera)